# Line integral exercise

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function such that $f(-1)=f(1)=0$ and $f>0$ in $(-1,1)$. Knowing that the graph of $f$ is containted in the semicircle $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$, $y \geq 0$, calculate $$\int_C F.ds,$$ where $C$ is the curve oriented counterclockwise and $$F(x,y)=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}-2xy,\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-x^2)$$

I've tried to see if $F=\nabla h$ because if that was the case, then the integral would be equal to $$h(1,0)-h(-1,0)$$

but I couldn't find such function. I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[*Hint*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B-y%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%20-%202%20x%20y%2C%20y%5D%20-D%5B%20x%2F%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%20-%20x%5E2%20%20%20%20%20%2Cx%5D)**:

If $F = (F_1,F_2)$, then $\partial_y F_1 - \partial_x F_2 = 0$, meaning $\nabla \wedge F = \mathbf{0}$.

Comment: I can consider the region D enclosed by the curve and the $x-axis$ and apply Green's theorem,but then $\iint_D( \partial_x F_2-\partial_y F_1)dxdy-\int_C' F.ds$ where $C'$ is the line segment that joins $(-1,0)$ with $(1.0)$, since both integrals are $0$, then the value of the original integral is $0$.

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: I've realized that $F$ has problems at $(0,0)$, so instead I could apply Green's theorem on the region enclosed by the graph of $f$ and the upper semicircumference,